# Flask routing to functions with same name in different modules

Tags: python, flask

If I have 2 files, e.g.:

`moduleA.py`

```
from MyPackage import app

@app.route('/moduleA/get')
def get():
    return "a"
```

`moduleB.py`

```
from MyPackage import app

@app.route('/moduleB/get')
def get():
    return "b"
```

and in `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
import IPython
import logging

app = Flask(__name__,
        static_url_path='', 
        static_folder='static',
        template_folder='templates')
from MyPackage import moduleA, moduleB
```

Then flask will throw an error `AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: get`

I presume that python itself doesn't see a conflict here because the functions are in 2 separate modules, however flask does. Is there a better standard to use here, or do i have to make the function names like `def getModuleA`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider using [Blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/)

> Factor an application into a set of blueprints. This is ideal for
>   larger applications; a project could instantiate an application
>   object, initialize several extensions, and register a collection of
>   blueprints.

Example:

```py
# module_a.py
from flask import Blueprint

blueprint = Blueprint('module_a', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/get')
def get():
    return 'a'

# module_b.py
from flask import Blueprint

blueprint = Blueprint('module_b', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/get')
def get():
    return 'b'

# app.py
from flask import Flask
from module_a import blueprint as blueprint_a
from module_b import blueprint as blueprint_b


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint_a, url_prefix='/a')
app.register_blueprint(blueprint_b, url_prefix='/b')

# serves:
#  - /a/get
#  - /b/get
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a variable in your route like so, which is the simpler solution if your application doesn't need to be modularized:

```
@app.route('/module/<name>')
def get(name):
   if name == 'a':
      return "a"
   else:
      return "b"
```

Else, you need to use [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/) if you want to have the same url endpoints but for different functions of an application. In both files, import Blueprint.

```
from flask import Blueprint
```

**moduleA.py**

```
moduleA = Blueprint('moduleA', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')

@moduleA.route('/moduleA/get')
def get():
return "a"
```

**moduleB.py**

```
moduleB = Blueprint('moduleB', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')

@moduleB.route('/moduleB/get')
def get():
   return "b"
```

And in your main app. file, you can register these blueprints like so:

```
from moduleA import moduleA
from moduleB import moduleB
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(moduleA) #give the correct template & static url paths here too 
app.register_blueprint(moduleB)
```